# Add Image src dynamic to HTML using C#

Tags: c#, html

I have image path store in my sql database
when i try to add the image dynamic using "InnerHtml" it don't work
 HTML code like this

```
<div runat=server class="ws_images" id="List_Slide">
</div>
```

C# Code like this

```
List_Slide.InnerHtml = "<li><img src=data1/images/31.jpg alt=31 title=31 id=wows1_0/>      </li>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an  with `runat="Server"` and set the 'src' property in Code Behind:

**HTML:**

```
<img runat="server" id="img31" />
```

**CS:**

```
((HtmlImage)img31).Src = "data1/images/31.jpg";
```

Comment: i have list of images ,cane you tell me how can i do this in div tag ?

Comment: do you know the count of them in advance ?

Comment: you can use the 'DataBinding' event to do so,
Add 'asp:Table' tag, and in the Code Behind, append TableRow(s) and TableCell(s) based on the count of Images Returned.